# Convert Project to SDK style and referenced project cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Converting project TEditor in my larger solution to use SDK with target frameworks including netstandard2.0.

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.0.54">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;MonoAndroid90</TargetFrameworks>
```

In visual studio I told different project BASE to reference that project TEditor.  Shows up in dependencies.
[image]

But when I have Using TEditor in CS code in Base, it does not find the TEditor (error on Using TEditor;).  Furthermore when I build Base I get CS0246 error:

```
...\PageModel.cs(12,7,12,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Base is using netstandard2.0
netstandard2.0
and both projects use

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.0.54">
```

Lastly I am getting DLL's produced from TEditor in correct bin/debug folders:
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TEditor, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

```
1>TEditor -> C:\Users\Brent\Documents\MyDataApp\Teditor\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\TEditor.dll
1>TEditor -> C:\Users\Brent\Documents\MyDataApp\Teditor\bin\Debug\monoandroid90\TEditor.dll
```

What am I missing and how can I diagnose further?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out my TEditor.dll was empty when I looked at the object browser.  With the new SDK setup I didn't have the correct Includes and it compiled and looked happy, because it wasn't including any code.